# MS Dynamics CRM 2015 assigning tasks to non CRM users

Tags: dynamics-crm

Is it possible to assign a Dynamics CRM task from outlook to someone who does not have a CRM license and keep track of the progress on CRM online.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options here.

1. Represent each non-CRM user as a contact record. Then add a new contact field to the task which CRM users can populate with the non-CRM contact. Only problem is that you can't use the assign and security model functionality but it doesn't sound like you need it. Also it means the 'my task' view for a CRM use will show the tasks being worked on by a non-CRM contact.
2. Represent each non-CRM user as a team. Give each team a security role. Then you use assign. Also when you assign then the record will disappear from the 'my task' view of the user.
3. Create a non-interactive user, but you are stuck with a limit of 5 for CRM Online.

[User and team entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328485.aspx)

> Non-interactive users are often used when writing service-to-service code because they do not use up a license. Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online allows for five free non-interactive users.

4. Not sure about this last one. You could try creating the user, giving them a security role, but not a license, e.g. so the user record is disabled. Then apparently you can assign them records still.

[Assigning Records to Inactive Users in Dynamics CRM](http://www.powerobjects.com/2013/09/25/assigning-records-to-inactive-users-dynamics-crm/)

> So long as the inactive user still maintains a security role, even though it is inactive, you can programmatically or via the UI assign records to that inactive user. This means that you can maintain the historical data of who owns a particular record even though they may no longer be with the company, and save yourself some extraneous licenses as well.

Answer (score 1):

Another option you could do that would complement what James has mentioned with regards to representing the non-CRM Users as contact records and then have an ISV solution like Peak Portals installed, http://www.peakengagement.com/peak-portals/ , that would allow these non-CRM users to log in via a website portal and see records associated to the CRM contact.